# Support HTTPS in Node.js server or require reverse proxy for HTTPS

Tags: node.js, http, https, open-source, reverse-proxy

I'm writing an open-source Node.js application that implements a HTTP server for API calls. Supporting HTTPS in Node.js isn't hard, but it adds a little complexity and cases you need to thing about:

- Path to key and cert should be configurable => More settings / documentation
- App should handle errors when key and cert is missing or path is wrong => More code and test
- Docker image must pass an external key and cert to the application running in the container => More code and documentation

It feels a bit like reinventing the wheel. I'm personally using a reverse proxy that handles the HTTPS part of all my sites. The servers in the background are all just HTTP.

Is it ok to require a reverse proxy or is it better to support HTTPS directly as most users aren't using a reverse proxy? What's the common server setup and recommend way when writing an open-source Node.js application? How to make it as easy as possible for most users to use my app?

Answer (score 0):

Reverse proxy is preferable for most of the scenarios since we can make use of security, load balancing, cache control, etc. kind of things. Also we can use for logging purpose so that we can maintain a security layer on all the server activities and data behind this proxy. As you mentioned, there will have some more lines of code to write but the system will persist more powerful. I recommend to have a reverse proxy to make the things more robust and secure.